# android: handover sms to default application

Tags: android

Please guide, in Android how can I pass my string (less then 160 char) to the default built-in SMS applicaion or queue, which will complete the process.

I mean, from my activity I want to call a built-in SMS application and pass my SMS string to that, then the built-in application will be responsible to rest of activity like SMS resending, etc.

Comment: Perhaps you could **accept** some answers ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To call the *default* sms application, with sms body and phone number :

```
Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse( "sms:" + phoneNumber ) );
intent.putExtra( "sms_body", smsBody );
context.startActivity( intent );
```

By *default* I mean the application chosen by the user. Actually it's better to start the *default* sms application than the *built-in* because you have to respect the user choice. If the device owner has chosen ChompSms as default SMS application, he will prefer your application launches ChompSms and not an other.

Comment: I do not see where that is documented in the SDK. Got a link? If it is not documented, it will not be reliable -- device manufacturers might replace the SMS application and not respond to this Intent, for example.

Comment: I found that in google groups (http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/2bc997d602d4bb4a).
It's working well on my samsung galaxy.

Answer (score 4):

To call the default sms application, with sms body and phone number :

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:123456789");   
    Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);   
    it.putExtra("sms_body", "The Hello How R U...");   
    startActivity(it);
```

Answer (score 3):

Beyond Thomas' answer, you can use [`ACTION_SEND` and `createChooser()`](http://www.androidguys.com/2009/11/02/a-call-to-action-action_send-that-is/) to allow the user to pick the application with which to send your message, whether that be the built-in SMS application or a third-party SMS application or email or GMail or Twidroid or whatever.

You can also use `SmsManager` to send the SMS yourself, but that will not pop up any built-in activity.

With luck, there is a spot in the documentation that covers Thomas's answer (elsewhere in this StackOverflow page), as that is the simplest solution to your request.

Comment: Does ACTION_SEND launch the sms application and wait for user to click "send" or direct send the SMS ? (SMS or mail or tweet...)

Comment: If you do not specify a destination, it will definitely wait, because it needs a number. The question does not state that the code has an SMS phone number.

Comment: ?????????? 
I dont want to launch that default or buildin application, I want to pass message body, phonenumer else to that application who must sent my sms directly without need user to click send (should not open any other interface)

can i put my sms in system sms queue for sending?

Comment: OK. Use SmsManager, as I wrote above.